# How can I use the voice recognition used by Android on Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development, voice-recognition

If I'm developing an Android app that uses TTS and Voice recognition, which libraries are used for the same voice recognition and speech on Ubuntu?

I'm assuming espeak for text to speech, but I'm unsure which voice recognition library and dictionary/learning/calibration system is used for voice recognition.

I'ld like to make the app available on Ubuntu Desktop.
*as well as test it outside an emulator*

Comment: check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/117505/is-it-possible-to-login-by-voice-recognition) but though there is no substantial answer

Comment: @devav2 thanks for the effort, but not really related.  voice login and which voice recognition toolkit is used on android (and if it is available in Ubuntu) are two completely different things.

Comment: You'll probably need to find out exactly what libraries Android uses elsewhere, then come back here and ask how to use them in Ubuntu. If you can't find it in Android documentation, [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=votes) might be of help.

Comment: Not sure about using it with Android, but Festival/festvox sounds much less robotic than espeak. As for the speech recognition, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition_in_Linux#Current_development_status might help.

Comment: Well, espeak comes standard on Ubuntu desktop now...so no dependency added.  On the other hand, the paid packages from cepstral are not horrifyingly expensive and they border on skeksi.

Comment: this guy is working on such things: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=HfrQrjH3AGw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use Google's [webspeech API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API) for your application. It uses the same technology as used on android.

Comment: If you edit in a little more data, I'll give this one the accept as well

Comment: Honestly, I've not had enough experience with their API to give you that info!

Comment: This might be an interesting complement: [A bare-bones project to bring google's speech-to-text to my desktop.](https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/shit-talk)

Answer (score 1):

1. Androids voice recognition relies on an internet connection, because the server has a substantial database of voice patterns. (I think)

   - Computers arent very good with voice recognition yet, so you need a huge database with alot of voices for the computer to cross reference and better understand words. (At least last i studied it)
   - As so, you cannot use it offline.
2. You can however use the voice recognition for writing via a workaround

   - By creating a remote desktop/vnc connection, and direct
   - or by using a remote keyboard application.

Chrome can use voice recognition for searches, and with an extension, can be used to fill out field data.
but as far as i know thats it.

and that's all i know.

Comment: I understand that voice recognition requires a corpus to learn words beyond simple phonetics and dictionaries (so fuzzy matches can be made when you don't enunciate).  I'm fine with requiring an internet connection if it's usable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use CMU Sphinx, it can be used as a toolkit to develop speech recognition both in Linux and Android: [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/)