# Voice Recognition at login page

Tags: login

I am thinking of using voice recognition for logging in.
I can code the voice recognition program (in java) but my question is how will I make it log in.

All I wanted is to tell the magic word and the program sees if it is right if so it logs me in by entering my login password or through any other means.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The "right" way would probably be to create a suitable PAM module: see this previous question: [Is it possible to login by voice recognition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117505/is-it-possible-to-login-by-voice-recognition). BTW it sounds like you're talking about *speech recognition* (recognizing a spoken password or phrase) rather than *voice recognition* (authenticating based on the specific biometric qualities of the individual's voice)

Comment: "I am thinking of using voice recognition for logging in" sorry? "orca" is the system for helping disabled. I would assume they can already login using their voice?!  There should be an option to enable it at the login page.